# Degrees symbol (as in Degrees Celsius/Fahrenheit) in a TextView

Tags: android, textview

Is there a way to include the small circular degrees symbol to a TextView? This would be for temperature readings, as in degrees Celsius or Fahrenheit.
I'm wondering if anyone has done this programmatically before.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

There is a Unicode symbol for Celsius degrees that you can use in Java: [`\u2103`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2103/index.htm). For Fahrenheit you can use [`\u2109`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2109/index.htm).

I have confirmed this works on Android Nexus S running Android version 2.3.6.

Example code:

```
temperatureValue.setText((result) + " \u2109");
```

Comment: Yes! It did work. I tried it on a 1.5 emulator and a 2.2 emulator, and tv.setText("\u2103") worked no problem.

Comment: If you just want the degree symbol without the C or F, use `\u00B0`.

Comment: How can i use this in kotlin ?

Comment: Concatenate strings like for example it is shown in this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44188301/371388
But instead of `"Hello"` and `"World"`, you can have for example `"Hello"` and `"\u2109"` for the intended unicode character

Comment: I'm looking for a table or dictionary. :)

Answer (score 36):

If Someone wants just the little circle sign without the letter, he can use:

```
\u00B0
```

Source:
[Unicode Character 'DEGREE SIGN'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b0/index.htm)

Answer (score 22):

in Activity
for Celsius

```
tempValue.setText((resultemp) + " \u2103");
```

for Fahrenheit

```
tempValue.setText((resultemp) + " \u2109");
```

for Kelvin

```
tempValue.setText((resultemp) + " \u212A");
```

for Romer

```
tempValue.setText((resultemp) + " \u00B0R");
```

---

In xml.file
for Celsius

```
android:text="\u2103"
```

for Fahrenheit

```
android:text="\u2109"
```

for Kelvin

```
android:text="\u212A"
```

for Romer

```
android:text="\u00B0R"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="\u00B0"/>
```

If sign is not visible on android studio layout preview, you need to add

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

to the root xml element.

Answer (score 1):

**For showing in XML, if you want to show android:text="32°C" you can use:**

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
android:text="32&#xb0;C"
android:id="@+id/myTV"></TextView>
```

**To do it programmatically, you can use:**

```
myTV.setText("32" + (char) 0x00B0+"C");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need only the degree (o) circle symbol you can copy below code.

```
char tmp = 0x00B0;
temperature.setText("60"+tmp);
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

For displaying `degree` symbol in a `TextView`, you can use from the "**& #176;**" without any distance. As you can see an example below:

`android:text="10& #176;c"
So this command will show you as a 10°c on the screen android.