# Display text in textview in android

Tags: android, textview

I want to display dynamically text in textview.

for example:
[image]

Like red color mark. to see celsius temperature symbol.

java code:

```
TextView txt_footer = new TextView(this);
txt_footer.setLayoutParams(childLayoutParams);
txt_footer.setText(weather.getMinTemp());
```

Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android set degree symbol to Textview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439517/android-set-degree-symbol-to-textview)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Degrees symbol (as in Degrees Celsius/Farenheight) in a TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312001/degrees-symbol-as-in-degrees-celsius-farenheight-in-a-textview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to make the Celsius degree symbol **red**:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("8<font color=""#f00"">°</font>"));
```

Note that I used the shor form for #ff0000 => #f00
You might prefer to use the named color "red", instead.

This is to make it the same color (**not red**):

```
TextView txt_footer = new TextView(this);
txt_footer.setLayoutParams(childLayoutParams);
txt_footer.setText(weather.getMinTemp() + "°C");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try,

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("8<sup>o</sup>"));
```

where sup is known as superscript, also you can do subscript by writing

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(Html.fromHtml("8<sub>o</sub>"));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
TextView txt_footer = new TextView(this);
txt_footer.setLayoutParams(childLayoutParams);
txt_footer.setText(weather.getMinTemp()  + " \u2109" + "C");
```