# Kotlin - How to correctly concatenate a String

Tags: string, kotlin

A very basic question, what is the right way to concatenate a String in Kotlin?

In Java you would use the `concat()` method, e.g.

```
String a = "Hello ";
String b = a.concat("World"); // b = Hello World
```

The `concat()` function isn't available for Kotlin though. Should I use the `+` sign?

Answer (score 206, accepted):

## String Templates/Interpolation

In Kotlin, you can concatenate using *[String interpolation/templates](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html#using-string-templates)*:

```
val a = "Hello"
val b = "World"
val c = "$a $b"
```

The output will be: `Hello World`

- The compiler uses [`StringBuilder`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-string-builder/) for *[String templates](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html#using-string-templates)* which is the most efficient approach in terms of memory because `+`/[`plus()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/plus.html) *[creates new String objects](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-concatenate-strings#using-the--operator)*.

Or you can concatenate using the [`StringBuilder`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-string-builder/) explicitly.

```
val a = "Hello"
val b = "World"

val sb = StringBuilder()
sb.append(a).append(b)
val c = sb.toString()

print(c)
```

The output will be: `HelloWorld`

## New String Object

Or you can concatenate using the `+` / [`plus()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/plus.html) operator:

```
val a = "Hello"
val b = "World"
val c = a + b   // same as calling operator function a.plus(b)

print(c)
```

The output will be: `HelloWorld`

- This will create a new String object.

Comment: the operator "+" is translated into plus(), so you can either write `a.plus(b)` or `a + b` and the same bytecode is generated

Comment: I looked into the bytecode and string interpolation uses StringBuilder internally

Comment: @crgarridos, Would this mean that for Kotlin using the string interpolation for concatenation `"Hello" + "Word"` is just as performant as using StringBuilder to append to a string, `someHelloStringBuilder.append("World")`?

Comment: string interpolation refers to the resolution of variables inside of a literal string. so technically yes.

Comment: Both string interpolation and concatenation use StringBuilder internally. The only difference I noticed in the bytecode is that if there is only a single character between two variables then interpolation uses append(Char) instead of append(String) for this character. So I would say it is just syntactic sugar. It is important to use StringBuilder when multiple concatenations are done to a single variable, e. g. in a for loop.

Comment: I'm just starting to learn Kotlin so this might be a stupid question, but I thought val values couldn't be changed. So why am I allowed to write, 

val name = StringBuilder("Peter")
name.append("Pan")

would this not be altering the name variable?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 30):

`kotlin.String` has a `plus` method:

```
a.plus(b)
```

See https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/plus.html for details.

Comment: The `+` operator is normal, not calling the translated operator function `plus`  ... this is not idiomatic

Comment: why do you think so ?

Comment: Don't forget to affect your result like I did, like `a = a.plus(b)` for instance

Comment: @lorenzo 's comment explains why this answer's less preferable to the solutions above. When concatenating is dependent on multiple if statements `plus()` is less practical than a `StringBuilder`'s append method ie.

Answer (score 13):

I agree with the accepted answer above but it is only good for known string values.
For dynamic string values here is my suggestion.

```
// A list may come from an API JSON like
{
   "names": [
      "Person 1",
      "Person 2",
      "Person 3",
         ...
      "Person N"
   ]
}
var listOfNames = mutableListOf<String>() 

val stringOfNames = listOfNames.joinToString(", ") 
// ", " <- a separator for the strings, could be any string that you want

// Posible result
// Person 1, Person 2, Person 3, ..., Person N
```

This is useful for concatenating list of strings with separator.

Answer (score 13):

Try this, I think this is a natively way to concatenate strings in Kotlin:

```
val result = buildString{
    append("a")
    append("b")
}

println(result)

// you will see "ab" in console.
```

Comment: it is `buildString {` instead of `stringBuild {`

Comment: @arnonuem I've fixed it (as you should have felt free to do).

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can concatenate using a `+` sign. Kotlin has string templates, so it's better to use them like:

```
var fn = "Hello"
var ln = "World"
```

`"$fn $ln"` for concatenation.

You can even use `String.plus()` method.

Comment: The `+` operator is normal, not calling the translated operator function `plus`  ... this is not idiomatic

Comment: Could you please explain why you think the plus version of + is not idiomatic ?

Answer (score 8):

Similar to [@Rhusfer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51318253/2914140) I wrote this. In case you have a group of `EditText`s and want to concatenate their values, you can write:

```
listOf(edit_1, edit_2, edit_3, edit_4).joinToString(separator = "") { it.text.toString() }
```

If you want to concatenate `Map`, use this:

```
map.entries.joinToString(separator = ", ")
```

To concatenate `Bundle`, [use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60543857/2914140)

```
bundle.keySet().joinToString(", ") { key -> "$key=${bundle[key]}" }
```

It sorts keys in alphabetical order.

Example:

```
val map: MutableMap<String, Any> = mutableMapOf("price" to 20.5)
map += "arrange" to 0
map += "title" to "Night cream"
println(map.entries.joinToString(separator = ", "))

// price=20.5, arrange=0, title=Night cream

val bundle = bundleOf("price" to 20.5)
bundle.putAll(bundleOf("arrange" to 0))
bundle.putAll(bundleOf("title" to "Night cream"))
val bundleString =
    bundle.keySet().joinToString(", ") { key -> "$key=${bundle[key]}" }
println(bundleString)

// arrange=0, price=20.5, title=Night cream
```

Answer (score 4):

The **most simplest way** so far which will *add separator* and *exclude the empty/null strings* from concatenation:

```
val finalString = listOf(a, b, c)
    .filterNot { it.isNullOrBlank() }
    .joinToString(separator = " ")
```

Answer (score 3):

There are various way to concatenate strings in kotlin 
Example -

```
a = "Hello" , b= "World"
```

1. Using + operator
   `a+b`
2. Using `plus()` operator

   `a.plus(b)`

**Note - + is internally converted to .plus() method only**

In above 2 methods, a new string object is created as strings are immutable. if we want to modify the existing string, we can use StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder str = StringBuilder("Hello").append("World")
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way of string concatenation is **String Interpolation** in Kotlin.

```
val a = "Hello"
val b = "World"

val mString = "$a $b"
val sString = "${a, b}, I am concatenating different string with."

//Output of mString : Hello World
//Output of sString : Hello World, I am concatenating different string with.
```

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatically correct way to do string interpolation in Kotlin is as follows

```
val helloString = "Hello"
val worldString = "World"
val concatString = "$helloString $worldString"
```

Output

```
Hello World
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have an object and want to concatenate two values of an object like

```
data class Person(
val firstName: String,
val lastName: String
)
```

Then simply following won't work

```
val c = "$person.firstName $person.lastName"
```

Correct way in this case will be

```
"${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}"
```

If you want any string in between concatenated values, just write there without any helper symbol. For example if I want "Name is " and then a hyphen in between first and last name then

```
 "Name is ${person.firstName}-${person.lastName}"
```

Answer (score 1):

yourString += "newString"

This way you can concatenate a string

Answer (score 1):

**In Kotlin we can join string array using `joinToString()`**

```
val tags=arrayOf("hi","bye")

val finalString=tags.joinToString (separator = ","){ "#$it" }
```

**Result is :**

> #hi,#bye

---

if list coming from server

```
var tags = mutableListOf<Tags>() // list from server

val finalString=tags.joinToString (separator = "-"){ "#${it.tagname}" }
```

**Result is :**

> #hi-#bye

Answer (score 1):

I suggest if you have a limited and predefined set of values then the most efficient and readable approach is to use the String Template (It uses String Builder to perform concatination).

```
val a = "Hello"
val b = "World"
val c = "$a  ${b.toUpperCase()} !"

println(c) //prints: Hello  WORLD !
```

On the other hand if you have a collection of values then use **joinToString** method.

```
val res = (1..100).joinToString(",")
println(res) //prints: 1,2,3,...,100
```

I believe that some suggested solutions on this post are are not efficient. Like using plus or + or creating a collection for a limited set of entris and then applying **joinToString** on them.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Addition Assignment (+=) Operator](https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/operators):

| Expression | Equivalent | Translates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a +=b | a = a + b | a.plusAssign(b) |

Basic usage:

```
var message = "My message"
message += ", add message 2"
```

Will output: `My message, add message 2`

---

Generic functions, with optional spaces between words:

```
fun concat(vararg words: String, space: Boolean = false): String {
    var message = ""
    words.forEach { word -> message += word + if (space) " " else "" }
    return message
}

fun concat(vararg words: String, separator: String = ""): String {
    return string.joinToString(separator)
}
```

Calling generic function:

```
concat("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")
concat("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", space =  true)
```

Output:

```
onetwothreefourfive
one two three four five
```