# How to append 2 strings in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-context

I am trying to concatenate 2 String but not sure how to go about it.

this is my code:

```
 val word = R.string.word
```

and i'm trying to append it with `"$currentPage/5"` inside the `setText("$currentPage/5")`
 i tried to make it in this way `setText("$word $currentPage/5")`
and this way `setText("${R.string.value} $currentPage/5")`
and it did not work , it only shows me numbers not the text

Comment: Check this link -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44188240/kotlin-how-to-correctly-concatenate-a-string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to use this:

```
val word = getString(R.string.word)
text_view.text = "$word $currentPage/5"
```

If you want to edit your value (e.g. current page) wrap it with {}
E.g.

```
val word = getString(R.string.word)
text_view.text = "$word ${currentPage/5}"
```

Remember to use proper kotlin syntax

Answer (score 2):

```
In Kotlin, the concatenation of string can be done by **interpolation/templates**.

val a = "Its"
val b = "Kotlin!"
val c = "$a $b"

The output will be Its Kotlin!

Or we can alson do concatenate using the **+ / plus() operator**:

val a = "String"

val b = "Concatenate"

val c = a + b   

val d =a.plus(b)

print(c)
The output will be: StringConcatenate

print(d)
The output will be: StringConcatenate

Or you can concatenate using the StringBuilder which is a normal way to do that.
```

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate two string, we could do

> val concatenatedWord = "${resources.getString(R.string.value)}:
>   ${number/3}."

If R.string.value was *"The result"* and number was *15*, value of concatenatedWord will be ***"The result: 5."***
Or we could also concatenate using the *+* operator or using *StringBuilder*.

But if you do 
  textView.text =  "${resources.getString(R.string.value)}: ${number/3}."
AS will warn *"Do not concatenate text displayed with setText."* so, in the case of setting concatenated text in textview, consider using

> String.format("%s: %d.", resources.getString(R.string.value):
>   number/3)

Answer (score 0):

As a future resource and answer why the accepted answer works:-

[String Templates](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#string-templates):-

Strings may contain template expressions, i.e. pieces of code that are evaluated and whose results are concatenated into the string.

How to implement these?

A template expression should start with a dollar sign ($) and consists of either a  simple name:

- when the expression is a simple variable.

  ```
    val i = 10
    println("i = $i") // prints "i = 10"
  ```
- or else arbitrary expression in curly braces:

  ```
    val s = "abc"
    println("$s.length is ${s.length}") // prints "abc.length is 3"
  ```

Note :- Templates are supported both inside raw strings and inside escaped strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
val nameOfAnimal = "fish"
val speciesClass =  "is an Aquatic Vertebrate"    
     
     println(nameOfAnimal.plus(speciesClass))
     println(nameOfAnimal+speciesClass)
     println("$nameOfAnimal   $speciesClass")
```

Results:

```
fishis an Aquatic Vertebrate
fishis an Aquatic Vertebrate
fish   is an Aquatic Vertebrate
```