# Kotlin - String interpolation $ vs concatenate using plus-equals +=

Tags: string, kotlin, string-concatenation, string-interpolation

The problem is quite simple:
What is the difference between these 2 versions (both have initialized `var name: String` and `val someInt: Int`)?

`name += " $someInt"`

`name = "$name $someInt"`

I also read that the [String interpolation `$` uses a StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44188301/13227011), so the second code should be preferred to the first one (which uses concatenation)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to find the difference is to look at the generated bytecode (I will use Kotlin 1.4.10).

Bytecode generated for `name += " $someInt"`:

```
ALOAD 0
NEW java/lang/StringBuilder
DUP
INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/StringBuilder.<init> ()V
SWAP
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
BIPUSH 32
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (C)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
ILOAD 1
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.toString ()Ljava/lang/String;
ASTORE 0
```

Bytecode generated for `name = "$name $someInt"`:

```
NEW java/lang/StringBuilder
DUP
INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/StringBuilder.<init> ()V
ALOAD 0
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
BIPUSH 32
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (C)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
ILOAD 1
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.toString ()Ljava/lang/String;
ASTORE 0
```

Results are pretty much the same, but in the first case there is an extra `SWAP` operation, cause argument for first `append` operation was loaded onto stack too early (before `StringBuilder` was created, and now they need to be swapped).

**TL;DR**

Turns out that:

1. `StringBuilder` is created in both cases
2. There are 3 appends (`name`, whitespace & `someInt`) in both cases
3. Second one is slightly more effective.

Comment: "Second one is slightly more effective".
Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

The semantics are equivalent, and the second one is probably slightly more efficient, but not exactly for the reason you give: it's that there's only one concatenation instead of two.  (The first one first generates `" " + someInt`, and then generates `name + (" " + someInt)`.)